# How to use python to develop office complement?

Tags: python, nlp, office-addins, officedev

I'm trying to develop a web add-in for office, but I have not managed to call a Python function from the Javascript API. My question is whether there is any way to call the Python function from the Javascript API, or some way to develop a plugin using only Python. It is necessary Python since in that language the algorithms of NLP are had for the analysis of the text.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ? 1 year later there is still nothing clear on web to do so :(